# url: $(form).attr('action') another folder

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jQuery/AJAX to submit a form. For security, I want the "action" (php) file to be outside the public folder (i.e., *../actionFolder/action.php* instead of *mydomain.com/actionFolder/action.php*). When I set the action to refer to the file outside the public folder the php file can't be found. It looks like the jQuery needs to be changed, but I am brand new to jQuery and can't find an answer.

Here the code I think is relevant:

HTML:

```
<form id="signupForm" method="POST" action="../actionFolder/action.php">
```

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: $(form).attr('action'),
  data: formData
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't think that is possible. But can't affirm it.

Comment: The web browser must have access to a page to post to it.  Consider securing your php file through alternate means.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
url : $("#signupForm").attr("action");
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Louys, Unfortunately, as you said, this doesn't work. I was hoping something could be added, like `url : $(../#signupForm).attr("action");`.